# using quotes in cucumber/capybara scenario

Tags: escaping, cucumber, capybara

Here is my step, and capybara doesn't seem to escape it properly thats why it's showing as:

And I should see 'Height (e.g. 5\'11\")'

Then /^I should see 'Height (e.g. (\d+)\'(\d+)\")'$/ do |arg1, arg2|
  pending # express the regexp above with the code you wish you had
end

I just need it to check the page if it has that string. Is this a capybara limitation? Or am I escaping it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like cucumber is unable to generate proper regexp for such string. But cucumber also works with [Multiline Strings](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments). So you can implement following code:

```
# web_steps.rb
Then /^(?:|I )should see following text:$/ do |text|
  page.should have_content(text)
end

# in your scenario
...
And I should see following text:
"""
Height (e.g. 5'11")
"""
```

It works to me. Hope it will help you too.

Comment: hmm gotta try that sometime. iwll let you know the rresults

Comment: The new link to that wiki page is https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Multiline-Step-Arguments

Comment: Thank you Ramon. I've fixed this link.